# On a microcontroller, is it possible to use polling to read the serial port without losing incoming data?

Tags: serial-port, embedded, real-time, microcontroller, hardware

On a microcontroller, is it possible to use polling to read the serial port without losing incoming data?

Assume my MCU has a 1 byte HW buffer for the UART.  At 115200 baud, that means I have about 70us to get an incoming byte before it's lost.  Even at 9600 baud, I have less than a ms.

Achieving that latency is very hard.  Moreover, on a RTOS, it runs a real risk of starving other threads (since e.g. FreeRTOS always runs a high priority task over a lower one).

Understood that polling is CPU expensive.  But in cases where CPU is available, it's also simpler.  But it seems its a non-starter to receive serial data if *anything* else is going on.  Is that correct? If not, how can you poll on a serial port receive?

Comment: It seems like you already understand the tradeoffs here, so what kind of answer are you expecting?  If someone takes the time to write an answer, what criteria are you judging it by?  Yes, it's possible to do it with polling but you're usually better off having a RX interrupt that stores the data in a ring buffer so you don't have to worry about timing so much.

Comment: @DavidGrayson My question isn't "What are the tradeoffs?" but rather "Is there _any_ way to read a serial port via polling without losing data?".  I expect that there is, because that seems to be common, at least for very simple cases - but I can't figure out how.

Comment: The Nyquist theorem provides you with the *minimum* polling rate. So at 9600 baud, your code has to poll the UART every half millisec, rather than what you assume. BTW you're misusing "*latency*".

Comment: @sawdust The MCU handles the individual bits at the hardware level, and places bytes in a buffer.  So we only need to read the single the buf before the next byte comes in (since it's a single byte buffer).  Nyquist is at the signal level, handled in HW by the MCU.

Comment: I'm aware of what the UART does. If the frames are arriving once per millisec, then the prudent poll rate is every half millisec rather than just once per millisec. If your system is incapable of handing UART receive interrupts, how is it going to manage *precise* polling that is never slower than the arrival rate?

Comment: @sawdust Yes, a 2x margin of safety would be nice but that's just an opinion.  Any polling rate faster than 1 ms will work if the bytes only come in once per millisecond.  All that matters is making sure the UART will not receive more than 1 byte between two consecutive polling times.  If you think we're wrong, provide a counter-example.  The Nyquist theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: Not sure where you get 70us from.  At 115200,N,8,1 the frame width is 87us, then the UART can buffer at least two characters, one in the shift register,and one in the data register, so that is 173us. Your mean polling interval must be <87us, but you can sustain single missed deadlines.  If the UART has a FIFO, or DMA capability the polling can be much less deterministic than that, depending on the amount of buffering provided.  If you are asynchronously streaming data, you probably don't want to use polling.  If the data can arrive unsolicited at any time, you are wasting CPU cycles polling.

Comment: "it's also simpler.", yes ignoring potential data loss _is_ simpler. Coping with data loss is less simple, and avoiding data loss less simple still.  Using interrupts (either UART or DMA) is the simplest way of avoiding data loss generally.  Otherwise it may depend on the nature of the application, and you will be "fixing" it for every application, so the _generalised_ safe solution is in fact simpler in the long run  - write once, use everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common scenario and there's a standard way to implement this. Polling would be senseless unless the program can be allowed to not do anything else for a long period of time.

What is used instead is the UART RX interrupt. From the ISR you store the incoming data in a ring buffer, where it will later be fetched by the background program. It is true that there's not much time between bytes, but once the whole protocol has been received there is usually plenty of time to decode, calculate CRC and so on.

That's how most old school MCU applications out there look like. Although it is not uncommon to design a setup where you let the interrupt trigger on the first byte and then poll remaining bytes from inside the ISR while allowing other interrupts to execute.

On modern MCUs you would not use UART RX interrupts but DMA, which solves the whole problem. So on new design which needs to support high baudrates, you would definitely aim for a MCU with DMA support.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend this, but if your UART receiver only has a 1-byte buffer (in addition to the shift register that receives incoming bytes) and you want to read data from it with polling (as opposed to an interrupt), you just need to poll faster than the data is coming in.

For example, you might design a main loop that takes care of several tasks, and one of them is read a single byte from the UART and process it.  Let's say you analyze your main loop and find out that it takes 200 µs or less to run (this info isn't provided by most compiler toolchains unfortunately, even though it would be very useful).  So your system cannot handle bytes coming in more often than once per 200 µs.  To prevent them from coming in faster than that, you could pick a baud rate that is less than (10 bits)/(200 µs) = 50000 bps.

Let's say you pick the standard baud rate of 38400 bps, where bytes take 260 µs.  After your program checks the UART, you know the data buffer is empty, and you know that you will be checking the UART again within 200 µs.  Between those two times where you check the UART, it is possible for one byte to finish being received, but not two, so there is no possibility of an overflow happening.

Adding on to this, let's suppose your system sometimes receives a command that takes a lot of time to process, like 2 ms.  Then you just tell your users that after sending that command they have to avoid sending any more commands for, say, 3 ms.

Comment: Note that a UART with a H/W FIFO allows missed deadlines to some extent, so long as the miss is not sustained and the _mean_ polling rate is fast enough.  Even without a FIFO all UARTs buffer at least two characters - one in the serial shift register and one in the data register, allowing a single missed deadline of up to 2 character periods.  On some MCUs DMA is also an option, in which case you can afford to poll the DMA flag much more slowly.

Comment: No.  You shouldn't call it a deadline if the MCU can miss it.  If you're getting a constant stream of bytes with the minimal UART buffering you described, and the UART receives a byte but then doesn't get polled for 12 bit times after that, there has to be an overflow because the shift register is occupied and there is no other place to store the first bit received of the next byte.

Comment: Point taken, my phrasing is incorrect.  The deadline is the point at which data is lost - up to 2x character period with no FIFO, but   variable, depending on how _late_ the previous poll was.  My point is that some aperiodic polling, with intervals greater than the character period is possible but not sustainable.  It was a note to the reader, not a criticism of the answer.

Comment: You simply _don't_ design UART RX with a 1 byte hardware by using polling, that's nonsense - or otherwise your program can't do _anything_ else but handling the UART. You have to use interrupts.

Comment: @Clifford Kind of depends on at what point the overrun flag is set by the UART peripheral - if that happens at the point when it has clocked in a whole frame (10 bits) or when it starts to clock in one. My experience suggests that the former is by far the most common but I wouldn't assume it. Similarly, if you are late at handling the RX flag but handle it and clear the flag, this must happen before the point where the hardware sets the RX flag for the next frame anew.